# Replacing usleep with nanosleep

Tags: c, usleep

I want to replace obsolete usleep function with nanosleep in my code:

```
static int timediff( struct timeval *large, struct timeval *small )
{
        return (   ( ( large->tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 ) + large->tv_usec )
                 - ( ( small->tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 ) + small->tv_usec ) );
}

struct performance_s
{
        struct timeval acquired_input;
};

performance_t *performance_new( int fieldtimeus )
{
     performance_t *perf = malloc( sizeof( performance_t ) );
     if( !perf ) return 0;

     gettimeofday( &perf->acquired_input, 0 );

     return perf;
}

performance_t *perf = 0;

int performance_get_usecs_since_frame_acquired( performance_t *perf )
{
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday( &now, 0 );
    return timediff( &now, &perf->acquired_input );
}


int fieldtime = videoinput_get_time_per_field( norm );


if( rtctimer ) {
    while( performance_get_usecs_since_frame_acquired( perf )
                  < ( (fieldtime*2) - (rtctimer_get_usecs( rtctimer ) / 2) ) ) {
        rtctimer_next_tick( rtctimer );
    }
} else {
    int timeleft = performance_get_usecs_since_frame_acquired( perf );
    if( timeleft < fieldtime )
        usleep( fieldtime - timeleft );
```

Questions: does this replacement get the same precision timing than with usleep ( and is it a correct replacement )?

```
struct timespec delay = {0, ( fieldtime - timeleft )}; nanosleep(&delay, NULL);
```

Answer (score 13):

One of the reasons `usleep` is obsolete is that the behavior when it was interrupted by a signal was inconsistent among historical systems. Depending on your needs, this may mean your naive replacement with `nanosleep` is not quite what you want. In particular, `nanosleep` returns immediately when any signal handler is executed, even if the signal handler was installed with `SA_RESTART`. So you may want to do something like:

```
while (nanosleep(&delay, &delay));
```

to save the remaining time if it's interrupted and restart sleeping for the remaining time.

Note also that `nanosleep` uses `timespec`, which is in *nanoseconds*, not microseconds. Thus, if your interval values are in microseconds, you must scale them by 1000 to make nanoseconds.

Also, be aware that it is an error (reported by `EINVAL`) to pass a nanoseconds value less than 0 or greater than 1000000000 (1 second). `timespec` values must be "normalized", i.e. the nanoseconds must be between 0 and 999999999 (inclusive) and larger values converted to use the seconds (`tv_sec`) field of the structure.

Answer (score 3):

Your underlying objective here is to sleep until `fieldtime` microseconds after the previous frame was acquired.  The `clock_nanosleep()` function allows you to do this directly - sleep until a particular absolute time has been reached - so it is a better fit for your requirement.  Using this function would look like:

```
int fieldtime = videoinput_get_time_per_field( norm );
struct timespec deadline = performance->input;

deadline.tv_nsec += fieldtime * 1000L;
deadline.tv_sec += deadline.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
deadline.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;

while (clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL) && errno == EINTR)
    ;
```

This presumes that you change `performance->input` to be a `struct timespec` set by `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &performance->input)` rather than `gettimeofday()`.  The `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock is a better fit for this case, because it's not affected by changes to the system time.